# Fade in images for all img tags without using additional ID's?

Tags: css, image, fadein

I'm trying to figure out how to have all my images on my site fade in because it looks great, however using this code requires all images to use "onload" an this is not practical.

• Ideally, it would be nice to just have all img use this effect, any ideas?

Here's the demo I've been using that looks great, I'd change the time to 300ms though:

HTML

```
<img onload="this.style.opacity='1';" src="image.jpg" />
```

CSS

```
img {
opacity:0;
-moz-transition: opacity 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: opacity 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: opacity 2s;
transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

Example:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UtnHS/)

What do you think is a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a jQuery solution.

This will fade all images in at the same time as soon as they're all loaded.

Remove the CSS and use this jQuery code instead (you'll need to include jQuery in your page first)

```
$(window).load(function () {
   $('img').fadeIn(2000); 
});
```

you can hide the images in jQuery first:

```
$(function () {
   $('img').fadeOut(0); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s72s9Lsv/

You can also use an each() function with a setTimeout() to do delayed fadeIns so they appear at different times.

But here is the real problem I have with this question.   You've no doubt seen this effect on other sites.  It isn't just an effect, it's a technique they use called "lazy loading" (you can download a jQuery script for that too).  What this means is when the page loads - it loads with no images.  Very quick.  Then one at a time, the javaScript comes in and starts to load up the URLs of those images - sometimes it even waits until you've scrolled down the page enough for the image to be relevant.   The fade-in effect you see is just a choice they made so that the image doesn't just blink into existence in a disturbing way.

Lazy loading is cool and if you've never done it before, you should give it a go.   You'll be proud of yourself.

Comment: Thanks @braks that's very helpful of you. I'm not strong at coding so I'm  curious, could you point me in the right direction to try this lazy loading technique? Is it as simple as copy and pasting some files to my site and having my code point to some script source?